# Switch to a filesystem with more memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, mount

I am relatively new to linux, but am working on a remote server.
Here's the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G  1.9G   28G   7% /
devtmpfs        252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            51G  1.0M   51G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb15      105M  5.2M  100M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop1       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15904
/dev/loop2       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/sdc1       2.4T   85M  2.2T   1% /mnt
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I am generating ~100GB of data from a program, hence the 29GB space is getting filled mid-program run on `/dev/root`.

1. Can I switch to either `devtmpfs` to `tmpfs` so that I am able to run this program? If yes, how?
2. If not, how can I merge these filesystems so `/dev/root` has more space?

Comment: `tmpfs` is not a persistent filesystem - it's stored in RAM and disappears when it's unmounted (so also when the system shuts down). You have a 2+TB filesystem at `/mnt`, why not use it? How are you running the program?

Comment: Writing to /devtmpfs may not be advisable as that is shared memory (unless you want ramdisk like characteristics for the data).    You can't practically merge /dev/root with /dev/devtmpfs as /dev/tmpfs is not a real disk filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, where your program writes to, you could either look into configuration or just mount the folder, where the program writes to, to a different drive and folder.

[mount command](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/)

Comment: Tried the following 2 commands, getting these errors:
`azureuser@da-tpch-dbgen-ubuntu2:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`. 
`mount: /mnt: /dev/sdc1 already mounted on /mnt.`. 
`azureuser@da-tpch-dbgen-ubuntu2:~$ sudo mount devtmpfs /dev`. 
`mount: /dev: special device devtmpfs does not exist.`.

Comment: Well, according to your list /dev/sdc1 is indeed already mounted as well as devtmpfs. It's already listed in the column in your OP.

Basically under /mnt/ you are already accessing the root folder of the partition /dev/sdc1. You could also just create a folder within it like /mnt/myspecialfolder and then mount the folder that is used by your program to it.

Comment: Right, so how do I make my program use these instead of /dev/root which just has 29GB?

Comment: Your program probably doesn't write directly to /, so you first should find the exact folder that is used.